# OpenCV imread() Method returns None

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, image-processing

I was playing around with the OpenCV library, and tried to open a small image, with the following code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'penguin.jpeg')
print(img)
```

To basically take a look at the array of pixels in the image, however the print simply returns **None**.

Both my .py file and the image are in my desktop, so I believe the problem is not the path.

I am also aware of some issues with `imread()` and JPEG images, however I get the same result with the PNG version of this image.
This had been working fine up until today, so I am kinda clueless.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening or what I might be doing less correctly?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you you ever tried looking at where you ran this code as in your terminal path

Comment: Path image is False .

Comment: @EdwinCheong thank you for the fast reply! i haven't no. It's something I've never explored to deeply

Comment: If the file is not in your current working directory, then you must include the path to the file

Comment: Try adding `print(os.getcwd())` to see what directory your script is running in... and therefore where it expects the image to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulting the [OpenCV-Python Tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) we are warned that

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but `print img` will give you `None`

where `print img` is the Python 2 analog of your `print(img)`.

The code you have written is *correct* and having replicated your problem, I print an array representation of a test penguin.jpeg image locally.

As commented by Rashid Ladjouzi, the path is probably incorrect especially given that you mention the script worked previously. I would test this with the following code which should return `True`:

```py
import os

print(r'penguin.jpeg' in os.listdir("."))
```

Comment: Hi @Anil I tried what you mentioned and it does indeed return false, however I don't get why since both files are in my desktop. Besides the print of the image works fine now, without me doing any changes to the code or the files place, wich I believe is also weird

Comment: You may be running your Python script from another directory. As a simple solution, please ensure to `cd` into the correct directory (i.e. your Desktop) before running the script.